# Angular 7 Service is undefined exception

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm new in angular and I'm trying to manage http error by [PrimeNg Toast](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/toast).
I have created the service that make the http call:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AttoService {

  apiEnv = environment.apiBase;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private handleError : HandleErrorService) { }

  getAtti() {
    return this.http.get<ApiResult<Atto[]>>(this.apiEnv + "Atti")
    .pipe(
      retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
      catchError(this.handleError.handleError) // then handle the error;
    );
  }
}
```

The HandleErrorService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HandleErrorService {

  constructor(private toastService: ToastService) { }

  public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      this.toastService.addSingle;
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };
}
```

As you can see with `this.toastService.addSingle;` I call the toast service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class ToastService {

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

  addSingle() {
    this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Service Message', detail:'Via MessageService'});
  }
}
```

The toast component is in the app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-tab></app-tab>
<app-toast position="top-rigth"></app-toast>
```

The service are injected by providers in app.module

```
@NgModule({
  providers:[HandleErrorService, MessageService, ToastService],
```

but I receive

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addSingle' of undefined
    at CatchSubscriber.push../src/app/service/handle-error.service.ts.HandleErrorService.handleError [as selector] (handle-error.service.ts:18)
```

Can you help me?Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  catchError(this.handleError.handleError) // then handle the error;
```

Using this line like that changes the context of the `this` keyword.

Replace it with either of those

```
  catchError(this.handleError.handleError.bind(this))
  catchError(err => this.handleError.handleError(err))
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that row changes the context of this keyword

Comment: That's basic javascript, and why the functions have `bind/call/apply` methods bound to them. [Take some time to read this](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/), it will greatly help you !

Answer (score 1):

`addSingle` is a method

```
  this.toastService.addSingle();
```

Comment: it's the same with this.toast.addSingle(); the toastServicve is undefined

Comment: @luca you are loosing `this` context. Apply answer above .